# Map User Profile (AD) property to mangad property for Display Template

Tags: 2013, user-profile-property, managed-property, display-template

I have "successfully" imported an extended property from AD and to be able to show this property in a display template for search I *Think* I have to map it to a managed property.

When I go to [CA > User Profile Svc > Manage User Profile] I can see that it has correct value and the name I gave it from the AD sync [Manage User Properties>New Property>Add new Mapping]

Again. I *Think* I'll have to map it to a managed property, so I tried going to [Site Settings > Schema] and I can find it in the "Crawled properties" list but when I select Edit Everything is Diabled and I cant add a mapping

1) Is it correct that I need to map my User Profile Property to a mapped property to be able to use it in th edisplay template

2) How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I go to

[CA > ...>Search Service Application > Schema] or 
[Site Settings > Site Collection Administration > Search Schema ]

instead of

[Site Settings > Search >  Schema]

I come to the same interface, but here I can create new managed properties and also map my user profile properties to managed properties.

And it works all the way to the display template, just dont forget to update the result type by going in to Site Settings > Result type. You will get a notification that you need to update your result types.

This is a good guide how to use managed properties in display template:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn794209(v=office.15).aspx